# Infragistics Toolbar tools (ControlContainer) size settings. Dock fill property could not be found

Tags: infragistics

I have a custom control structure as follows

ToolbarsManager

--MainMenuBar

--**MyCustomToolbar**(Contains only one tool)

    --**ControlContainer Tool**(Contains only my Custom Control)

        --**CustomUserControl**

I want to adjust their width. By setting ToolbarsManager's FillEntireRow property width of custom toolbar has been adjusted. But the width of control container tool and custom control could not be set. **I want them all to be filled to entire row.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the ControlContainerTool.SharedProps.Spring to True. I believe that will increase the tool's width when it is in a toolbar with FillEntireRow set to True.

Comment: There are 3 lines to take care of
    `cntool.InstanceProps.Spring = DefaultableBoolean.True;

    cntool.SharedProps.Spring = true;

    cntool.CanSetWidth = true;`